# VMWare NAT mode guest no access to Internet

Tags: networking, configuration, vmware, nat, vmware-workstation

I am using VMWare Workstation 15 on a Windows 10 host. I want to set up my guests' network using NAT. In this case, the guests can access services running on the host using a fixed address without considering the network configuration outside the PC.

### Configuration:

#### Host

Interface 1: 192.168.100.xxx in 192.168.100.0/24 (router-Internet)

Interface 2: 10.0.0.1 in 10.0.0.0/24 (VMnet2)

VMnet2 in VMware: [VMnet2 Configuration Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGHCv.png)

#### Guest

Interface: 10.0.0.100 in 10.0.0.0/24 (VMnet2)

```
Ethernet adapter Host-NAT:
    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : localdomain
    Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::ad5d:7c44:696a:7c01%15
    IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.101
    Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
    Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.1
```

### Symptoms

#### Problem

- The guest cannot access the Internet. (Pinging hosts on Internet result is timeout)

#### What works

- The host can ping guests.
- Guests can ping the host.
- Guests can ping each other.

[Wireshark on VMnet2 Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmQcb.png)

### Checked

- All VMWare services are running.
- Firewall is disabled on both host and guest.
- Reboot host or guest not works.

Answer (score 3):

### Solution

Change Gateway in DHCP to 10.0.0.2.

### Description

The 10.0.0.1 is indeed the host's address. However, unlike a standard router, the VMWare NAT host the gateway service on 10.0.0.2, not 10.0.0.1, thus all traffic sent to 10.0.0.1 will not be NATed.

Comment: Note that this is the correct answer *even* if the configuration shows that the gateway is at .1, vmware just refuses to listen there. You need to change the vmware settings to .2 for it to work. (This took me more hours to figure out than I'd like to admit, I saw one or two posts about using .2, but my config clearly said .1 so I used that. Wtf.)

Answer (score 0):

Try: Edit → Virtual Network Editor → Restore Defaults.

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which [a comment should be used instead of an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173)). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."